# 10/89 (1990) Subaru Legacy EJ22 - OBDI Code 45

Tags: subaru, air-intake, legacy, obd-i

10/89 Subaru Legacy EJ22.  NA.  Multiport Fuel Injection.

Throwing...

> Code 45: Pressure duty solenoid (turbo)/atmospheric pressure sensor circuit
>   (non-turbo)

Where is this thing located?

I have 2 guesses but want to make sure...  Guess 1) Passenger side underneath the intake between the manifold tubes there is a square looking thing with 2 vacuum lines and a connector.. Guess 2) Between the air filter and the intake, has the single multi pin connector.

Update:
Pictures on the internet seem to think this is sitting right in front of the strut on the passenger side.  I have nothing there...

Update2: "The atmospheric pressure sensor is located inside the ECU", don't know if this is true or not.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Additional Info: http://forums.nasioc.com/forums/showthread.php?t=337979 - The Legacy777 guys seems to be pretty confident about it being in the ECU

Answer (score 1):

The atmospheric pressure sensor is located in the ECU per Mitchell. This is fairly common across makes. Try clearing the codes and if the code comes back replace the ECU.

Comment: Thanks @Ben.  We are grabbing a wrecking yard computer to test this out. Will have feedback soon.